# Is it possible to configure a work iPhone to have the company user and the personal user separated?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a company's iphone, and I would like to use it for personal purposes, as well as a testing device. 
The problem is that this is the only test device of the company, and since I'm allowed to use it with my personal phone number and data, the problem is that any day, somebody can request the phone to use it for test something (it's very improbable but posible)
For this reason, I would like to know if it's posible to "lock" my personal user/data and/or switch to another user (the company's user) in a safe way so I can share the phone without having to be worried about somebody else seeing my what's app push notifications, my personal camera roll, etc...

Comment: You can't. This isn't android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible with iPhones.

Your only option is to take an encrypted backup and deleting everything on the iPhone before giving it out to another user, and then restoring your backup when you get it back.

Comment: I agree with the overall “ no” - there is not separate account support everywhere, but what about multiple iCloud? A personal account on the device would allow a quick removal of that account and all associated data. Adding it back would re-sync the personal data, no? [Apple classroom](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206151) automates this for a special case, but seems overkill to set up for a test device. Maybe I’m missing something else that could partially help.

Comment: It doesn't help with the specifics listed in the question such as avoiding push notifications from apps like Whatsapp, but it can be a kind of partial solution yes.